# Lightweight DBAL for python

Tags: python, postgresql, recommendation-engine, dbal

can somebody please recomend me some python DBAL library that will best suit my requirements. I would like to write my sql statements directly, most of the logics will be in db stored procedures (postgresql), so I only need to invoke db procedures, pass arguments to them and fetch the results. The library should help me with quoting (preventing sql inject). 
I played with sqlalchemy, but i think that there is no quoting helper when writing sql statement directly to engine.execute method.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python PostgreSQL modules. Which is best?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144448/python-postgresql-modules-which-is-best)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have given sqlalchemy a deeper look;  It does a fine job of quoting placeholders:

```
>>> engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
>>> engine.execute("select ?", 5).fetchall()
[(5,)]
>>> engine.execute("select ?", "; drop table users; --").fetchall()
[(u'; drop table users; --',)]
```

Comment: Oh dear... This is it :-O i have never seen it in tutorial or sql alchemy book... I really should give it deeper look. Thank you!

Comment: If you mean the [O'Reilly book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596516147/), that only covers sqlalchemy 0.4.0; It's very out of date.

Answer (score 0):

psycopg2 (via DB-API) will automatically quote to prevent SQL injection, IF you use it properly. (The python way is wrong; you have to pass the parameters as arguments to the query command itself.)

**WRONG:**

```
cur.execute('select * from table where last="%s" and first="%s"'
     % (last, first))
```

**RIGHT:**

```
cur.execute('select * from table where last=%s and first=%s',
     (last, first))
```

Note: you don't use %, and you don't put quotes around your values.

The syntax is slightly different for MySQLdb and sqlite3. (For example, sqlite uses ? instead of %s.)

Also, for psycopg2, always use %s even if you're dealing with numbers or some other type.

Comment: Also, psycopg2 tends to be much faster (possibly hundreds of percent faster). If you're comfortable with SQL and don't need the abstraction layer, you'll see much greater performance since you're much closer to the data.